# Island Perimeter Algorithm Too Slow

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on the island perimeter problem from LeetCode, and although I have a working solution, it only passes 5817 / 5833 test cases. I consider that a success, but obviously it's not efficient enough to handle the very large size "islands", and it will nag at me if I don't figure out what's causing the performance issues. For those of you unfamiliar with the "island perimeter" problem, here's a link to the LeetCode page.

[Island Perimeter Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/island-perimeter/#/description)

I've been solving the problems in Python to refamiliarize myself with the language and hopefully teach myself some new tricks, so it may just be something I'm doing inefficiently that someone can help me make better. Can anyone see any glaring problems with the algorithm below in terms of efficiency?

```
def islandPerimeter(self, grid):
    """
    :type grid: List[List[int]]
    :rtype: int
    """
    start = self.locateIsland(grid)
    return self.islandHelp(grid, start)

def islandHelp(self, grid, start):
    # get the perimeter of this position
    p = self.getPerimeter(grid, start)
    # mark this position as visited so we don't count it repeatedly
    grid[start[0]][start[1]] = 2
    # offsets to current positions to find land to the sides
    sides = [[-1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1]]
    for side in sides:
        newPos = [(start[0] + side[0]), (start[1] + side[1])]
        if ((newPos[0] in range(len(grid))) and
        (newPos[1] in range(len(grid[newPos[0]]))) and
        (grid[newPos[0]][newPos[1]] == 1)):
               # recursively find perimeter of connected land
               p += self.islandHelp(grid, newPos)
    return p

def getPerimeter(self, grid, pos):
    p = 0
    # offsets to find the neighboring positions
    sides = [[-1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1]]
    for side in sides:
        if (((pos[0] + side[0]) in range(len(grid))) and
            ((pos[1] + side[1]) in range(len(grid[pos[0] + side[0]])))):
            if (grid[pos[0] + side[0]][pos[1] + side[1]] == 0):
                # in bounds of grid, but not a land mass, add to perimeter
                p += 1
        else:
            # out of bounds means edge of grid, add to perimeter
            p += 1
    return p

def locateIsland(self, grid):
    # iterate through the grid to find a 1 and use that as start position
    for r in range(len(grid)):
        for c in range(len(grid[r])):
            if (grid[r][c] == 1):
                return (r, c)
    return (-1, -1)
```

Comment: Try to do without recursion, backtracking and all that. Keep it simple.

Comment: The given link does not lead to a description of the problem. Please provide it. Possibly contour tracing ? http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a check like this:

`(pos[0] + side[0]) in range(len(grid))`

The following things are happening:

- Python creates a list of size len(grid) containing the integers [0,1,2,3,...]
- Python takes your number (in this case pos[0] + side[0]), and, *for every integer in the list*, compares it to that integer to see if it is the same.

This is not efficient if all you want to know is if the number is smaller than the length of the grid! You can replace that line with

`(pos[0] + side[0]) >= 0 and (pos[0] + side[0]) < len(grid)`

to get the same effect, in a much shorter time. I made this changed and checked that it passes all cases when this is done.

Comment: This is weird... I did the same thing, and now the details of my submission say I passed 5833 / 5833 test cases, but it still says Time Limit Exceeded and rejects my submission.

Comment: I submitted it again and it accepted it... nice to know that I can succeed OR fail with my algorithm depending on the performance of the server...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below solution:

```
class Solution:
    def islandPerimeter(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        
        # Find no of rows in grid
        row = len(grid) 
    
    # Initialize perimeter
    perimeter = 0
    
    # Check if grid is empty
    if (row == 0):
        return perimeter
    
    # Find no. of columns
    col = len(grid[0])
    
    
    # Loop through the matrix
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            if(grid[i][j]==1):
                perimeter += self.getSideCount(grid,i+1,j,row,col) # Bottom Node
                perimeter += self.getSideCount(grid,i-1,j,row,col) # Top Node
                perimeter += self.getSideCount(grid,i,j+1,row,col) # Right Node
                perimeter += self.getSideCount(grid,i,j-1,row,col) # Left Node
    
    return perimeter


def getSideCount(self, grid: List[List[int]], i: int, j:int, row:int, col:int) -> int:
    # Check border conditions and if 
    if i<0 or j<0 or j>=col or i>=row or grid[i][j] == 0:
        return 1
    
    return 0
```